# Can I get a feature request that was migrated to MSO brought back?

Tags: discussion, migration, mso-mse-split

[Provide user interface to insert language hints](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254432/2072269) was posted before the MSE/MSO split, incorrectly closed as a duplicate, re-opened, had [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) inserted into it by OP (in hopes of migrating to MSO), and then was migrated to MSO.

However, there's nothing in it specifically about SO. Syntax highlighting is used in a number of SE sites, and all of them could benefit from the proposed feature-request. It's a feature that I'd like to have. I think MSE is really the place for asking for it. Can I get it migrated back? If not, should I post another question stating the same things?

Comment: Stack Overflow developers look at all feature requests whererver they have been posted. I think it's unlikely that moving it would have any effect on the likelihood that they would do something about it.

Comment: True, but for users supporting it it is currently hard to find @rob

Comment: I kind of agree. It'd be applicable to prog.se, codereview and others that are related to programming and require tag-related language stuff - so it's not necessarily completely SO based. However - given the nature of how it was migrated - a mod can't do this - it'd have to be a CM/dev.

Comment: @JonClements from the original post, it seems Tim Post did it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/149082/revisions, so I suppose any mod would do.

Comment: @muru nope - it's over 60 days old for a start, and the option doesn't even appear (it normally says - too old to migrate - but it's just not there) - so - I'm guessing us mere SO mods can't do it :)

Comment: @JonClements Ah. :D Thanks for trying. :) Now that you mention it, how did *I* find the original post? O.o I had it open in my browser for a couple of days, so I have no recollection of how I got there, and the current MSE post has no indication it was ever migrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion that is a feature request that would fit here on MSE.

The best thing you can do is flag the question and explain why you want it to migrate back to MSE. A moderator can set up the move.

If your flag is declined, first read carefully why it was declined, maybe there was a good reason the migration was rejected. If you have gone through all that, you could post another question here pointing to the other question.

Comment: Apparently a mod did try, but they can't. See Jon Clement's comments on the question. So I'll wait around to see if dev weighs in, if not, then post the feature request myself.